# centos7: boot error dracut-initqueue after converting virtual disk

Tags: hyper-v, kvm-virtualization, centos7, boot, dracut

I installed centos7 on Ubuntu 16.04 KVM with qcow2 disk format.

To deploy my centos machine I need it in vhdx disk format to support Microsoft's Hyper-V. I used qemu-image to convert it from qcow2 file format to vhdx.

```
qemu-img convert -O vhdx centos.qcow2 centos.vhdx
```

When I create in Microsoft's Hyper-V a new generation 1 VM with the centos.vhdx disk file I get an error like:

```
dracut-initqueue[220]: Warning dracut-initqueue timeout - starting timeout scripts
```

See my bootscren: [image: Bootscreen]

How I can fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the Centos7 DVD, boot from the DVD and rescue a centos system.

Follow this:
https://wiki.centos.org/TipsAndTricks/CreateNewInitrd

Be sure to skip to "to build it for a specific kernel version"

I have had the same going from Virtualbox to Hyper-V.

Comment: Not working if your partitions are not visible to installer. Like missing drivers.

Answer (score 7):

Run this in the VM before you clone it:

`dracut --force --no-hostonly`

After you clone the VM, boot it and run:

`dracut --force`

If you've already cloned the VM, you can connect the virtual disk to IDE to boot it (as noted by others) and run the first command. Make sure you shutdown the VM and re-attach the disk to the correct controller before running the second command.

The first command rebuilds the initramfs with all drivers available. The second command rebuilds the initramfs with only the drivers needed by the current system (default). Tested by going from Hyper-V to ESXi 6.5 w/ PVSCSI.

From: https://fedoramagazine.org/initramfs-dracut-and-the-dracut-emergency-shell/

Comment: Thanks, I had a working '0-rescue' option in my grub menu, and I was able to do `dracut --force` from there.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue trying to complete a fresh CentoOS 7 install on a Dell Laptop.  Found the answer [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/warning-dracut-initqueue-timeout-starting-timout-scripts-4175602645/):

> After the timeout error message finishes, you are entered to dracut
> commandline just type

```
blkid
```

> Find the LABEL = ***** associated with the device you are trying to boot from and then reboot.
> In the selection
> page choose to edit or press whichever key it is to edit and then
> delete the name that is on there next to LABEL and add what you got
> from the blkid. don't change anything else.
>
> this
> should fix it. if not try might a different usb creator.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting the QCOW2 image to VHDX I have converted it to VMDK.  Then 
reformatted the VMDK and successfully brought it up in ESXi 5.5, but the I'm unable to bring it up in ESxi 6.5.

With 6.5 ESXi I'm getting the error `/dev/disk/by-uuid/xxxxxxxxxxxx does not exist`

[image: error screenshot]

Then I've found a workaround for ESxi 6.5. In the VM settings if we change the Virtual Device Node from SCSI Controller to IDE master it will fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I was working with a virtual appliance builtin with CentOS, created to be running on VMware in a format OVA. After to import in VirtualBox, I had the same issue "dracut-initqueue" after same time appears the message about the timeout.
Someone had commented that start to works after change the controller device from Iscsi to IDE, I did that, and works. Now my appliance is running on CentOS.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was importing a VMWare ESXi generated ova to VirtualBox. There was no rescue kernel image to boot so I wasn't able to rebuild the initramfs. Turns out I didn't need to... simply changing the VirtualBox appliance settings (controller type: PIIX4, Hard Disk: IDE Primary Master) fixed my boot issue.